# Jmeter plugin Synthesis Report: How can we get 95th percentile response time?

Tags: jmeter

As I am interested only in steady-state (1 peak hour) figures from the results, I used the Jmeter plugin Synthesis Report(Filtered) from 1800 to 5400 as my ramp-up was 30min. By default it displays only the 90th line so how can I get 95th and 99th percentiles?

Do I need to add the below lines in the user.properties file to get both?

aggregate_rpt_pct1=95
aggregate_rpt_pct1=99

Thanks,
Naga

Comment: I added both the lines as I want both 95th and 99th but it takes only the last line and  displays only 99th. How do I get both 95th and 99th?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Synthesis Report supports more than one percentile column, if you want to have two - you will need to go for the [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report).

If additionally you need to filter the ramp-up period it can be done using either [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) or [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterpluginscmd)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. Should it be executed from bin folder of Jmeter after placing the input file in the same directory (bin). Should the Input file be the Raw data file produced or an Agrregated.csv file? I am using Mac

Comment: It can be executed from whatever place. Input should be "raw" .jtl results file. Good for you, try asking the question to Apple support.

Comment: but I have used Simple Data Writer to generate .csv and executed the test in GUI without any other listeners.